Can you make one immune to Death Note by intentionally misspelling their name thrice then trick someone to accidentally misspell it once?
From this answer

"The Death Note will be rendered useless if the victim's name is misspelled four times."
Rule IX

and

"If a Death Note owner accidentally misspells a name four times, that person will be free from being killed by the Death Note. However, if they intentionally misspell the name four times, the Death Note owner will die.
The person whose name was misspelled four times on purpose will not be free of death by a Death Note."
Rule XXXV

Reading those rules I see no reason why someone can't misspell a name on purpose 3 times and trick someone else into misspelling the name by accident to make them untouchable by the Death Note.
Is this right?

Does each Death Note owner get the same book?

While it's definitely one-topic here, I note that there are over 200 questions about Death Note over on the Anime & Manga stack, vs 15 (some closed) on this site; so you might find you get better/quicker answers by asking there.

you're right, is there an easy way to move the question?

I tried to make a question then delete this one but I found I couldn't post on anime stack
